# Check Load Balancer in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

Is there a way to check that the Load Balancer is working in Kubernetes?
I've created an external Load Balancer for an App Service running in three pods and I was curious if is there a way to check that this Load Balancer is sending traffic randomly or distributing it across the pods.

Comment: Hi, can you tell more about the setup that you are having? Which cloud provider are you using with your Kubernetes cluster? Do I assume correctly that you are using Azure (by `App Service`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can 2 options,

1. You can check your cloud providers network logs
2. You can call basic api get with curl to test manually and check pods logs.

`curl --location --request GET 'http://YOUR-LB-SVC.NAMESPACE/YOUR-GET-API'`